# Error when installing libssh build with make install

Tags: cmake, gnu-make, libssh

#### OS and CMake prehistory

I'm trying to install`libssh` on Debian GNU/Linux 9.5. I have successfully built the libssh source with cmake and put all the content inside `build` dir that I had created as advised in the install manual. (Note that I did not built the source with zlib as it is only optional) Note: There was no error when building the source with cmake.

[Install Manual of libssh](https://github.com/substack/libssh/blob/master/INSTALL)

#### Problem: Error with make install

The install manual now prompts you to install `libssh` by running

> make install

in the `build` dir. Now if I do that I get the following error message:

```
[ 84%] Linking CXX executable libsshpp_noexcept
CMakeFiles/libsshpp_noexcept.dir/libsshpp_noexcept.cpp.o: In function `main':
libsshpp_noexcept.cpp:(.text+0xb2): undefined reference to `std::cout'
libsshpp_noexcept.cpp:(.text+0xb7): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
libsshpp_noexcept.cpp:(.text+0xcd): undefined reference to `std::cout'
libsshpp_noexcept.cpp:(.text+0xd2): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
libsshpp_noexcept.cpp:(.text+0xdc): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
libsshpp_noexcept.cpp:(.text+0xe7): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
CMakeFiles/libsshpp_noexcept.dir/libsshpp_noexcept.cpp.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
libsshpp_noexcept.cpp:(.text+0x163): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
 libsshpp_noexcept.cpp:(.text+0x178): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
 CMakeFiles/libsshpp_noexcept.dir/libsshpp_noexcept.cpp.o:(.data.DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0[DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0]+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
examples/CMakeFiles/libsshpp_noexcept.dir/build.make:96: recipe for target 'examples/libsshpp_noexcept' failed
make[2]: *** [examples/libsshpp_noexcept] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:431: recipe for target 'examples/CMakeFiles/libsshpp_noexcept.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [examples/CMakeFiles/libsshpp_noexcept.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:149: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What is causing this issue and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The libssh build has some example files inside `../libssh/build/examples` on how to use the library. If you want to install libssh with `make install`, the `Makefile2` inside `../libssh/build/CMakeFiles` has specified that the example files are also compiled with your installation. Now the problem was that these example files have some errors inside, which is why the compilation/installation of libssh resolved in the error stated in the question above.

Now to resolve this issue you have to delete the `libsshpp_noexcept.dir` and `libsshpp.dir` inside the `../libssh/build/examples/CMakeFiles` folder. For the installation to succeed, you must also delete the corresponding lines of code in `Makefile2` (inside `../libssh/build/CMakeFiles`) that are responsible to compile these two example files. Open `Makefile2` in your preferred texteditor and search for `examples/CMakeFiles/libsshpp_noexcept.dir/build` and `examples/CMakeFiles/libsshpp.dir/build` in the file. You now have to delete everything that checks and installs/compiles these two files/dirs. I deleted the following parts:

> #==================================================
>
> delete everything inside here
>
> ...
>
> #==================================================

By deleting the content inside the seperators, you delete the installing/compilation procedure of the two (not necessary) example files provided by libssh.

Now run `make install` inside `../libssh/build` and you should be good to go.